# Scrambling string letters in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to figure out how to scramble letters in 1 area of an array/list in python IDLE. After looking on this site for answers I came across a code (I can't find it now) so I edited it a bit because it only worked with one string in the array. This is what I got

```
import random
word1 = input("Enter a phrase / word: ")
str_var = ["sa",word1]
r=list(str_var[1])
random.shuffle(r)
print (''.join (r))
```

As you can see I need to use variable 'r' as a middle man. It works but I feel it is needlessly long.

```
import random
word1 = input("Enter a phrase / word: ")
str_var = list["sa", word1]
random.shuffle(str_var[1])
print (''.join (str_var[1]))
```

How do I cut out the middle man?
Here is the error I got if it of any use:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/Delete Me.py", line 3, in <module>
    str_var = list["sa", word1]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you get the error that you get because you used a wildly wrong syntax for creating the list:

```
str_var = list["sa", word1]
```

`list` is a *function* and so its arguments should go between `(..)` and not `[..]`. But as you are constructing the list anyway at that very line, you don't need to explicitly call `list`.

Then your code still does not work. `random.shuffle` expects a list of its own, not a string – which is what `word1` is at that point. So this is what I did:

```
random.shuffle(list(str_var[1]))
```

and indeed it works (it does not give an error). But the original `str_var` value is not changed... After a closer look, I realized that `list` returns a *new* list here, which gets shuffled and then gleefully thrown away. The argument of `random.shuffle` should therefore be an existing variable. Explicitly creating `str_var[1]` as a list in the first place, finally solved that:

```
import random
word1 = 'hello'
str_var = ["sa", list(word1)]
random.shuffle(str_var[1])
print (''.join (str_var[1]))
```

Result:

```
lhloe
```

<sup>Your result may be different.</sup>